# Php with Mysql , Query not working

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I did wrote piece of php code to show 'product' name from a database.But nothing shows up after executing,Database is ok,i double checked database,table name,other fieldsI couldn't figure out the error so please help.

code

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root');
mysql_select_db('cybersoft');

$no=1;

$res=mysql_query("select product from test where 'serial'=$no ");

while($rowa=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo $rowa[1];
}
?>
```

Comment: The use of the mysql_* functions is not recommanded. Have a look at PDO http://php.net/PDO

Comment: put serial in backticks not in single quotes. Your comparing a literal string with an integer.

Comment: you missed third parameter in `mysql_connect()` which is password.

Answer (score 1):

Change single quote (**'**) to **`** or just remove. Quotes are used for string types.

```
 select product from test where `serial`= $no
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `mysql_connect()` takes three parameters.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword');
```

and to see an error you can use `mysql_error()` function

```
mysql_query('some query') or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your quotes around serial, they are not needed. This should work:

```
$res=mysql_query("select product from test where serial=$no");
```

If result is still empty, double check that there is a row with serial = 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('cybersoft');


$res=mysql_query("select product from test where serial=" . $no);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around `"serial"`, or make them backticks instead.

Also, you likely aren't seeing anything when you run the script because you don't have error reporting turned on. Do that in php.ini or programatically:

error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 mysql_connect('localhost','root');
 mysql_select_db('cybersoft');

 $no=1;

 $res=mysql_query("select product from test where serial='$no' ");

 while($rowa=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
     echo $rowa[1];
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$res=mysql_query("select product from test where serial=$no");
```